# Parse magento json in java

Tags: java, json, magento

I need to parse json files using java to use in jsp files.

For example, using the REST API in Magento whene I call this URL : 
magento/api/rest/products?limit=2.

I have something like this :

```
{
"16":
{"entity_id":"16",
"attribute_set_id":"38",
"type_id":"simple",
"sku":"n2610",
"model":"2610",
"dimension":"4.1 x 1.7 x 0.7 inches ",
"description":"The Nokia 2610 is",
"in_depth":"Integrated camera",
"activation_information":"Conditional $250 Equipment Discount Included",
"meta_keyword":"Nokia 2610, cell, phone, ",
"short_description":"The words \"entry level\" no longer mean \"low-end,\" especially when it comes to the Nokia 2610",
"custom_layout_update":"",
"status":"1",
"tax_class_id":"2",
"color":"24",
"visibility":"4",
"weight":"3.2000",
"price":"149.9900",
"cost":"20.0000",
"name":"Nokia 2610 Phone",
"manufacturer":"20",
"url_key":"nokia-2610-phone",
"meta_title":"Nokia 2610",
"meta_description":"Offering advanced media and calling features without breaking the bank, The Nokia 2610 is an easy to use",
"gift_message_available":"",
"options_container":"container2",
"custom_design":""},

"17":
{"entity_id":"17",
"attribute_set_id":"38",
"type_id":"simple",
"sku":"bb8100",
"model":"8100",
"dimension":"4.2 x 2 x 0.6 inches ",
"description":" Like the BlackBerry 7105t",
"in_depth":"1.3 mega pixel camera to capture those special moments",
"activation_information":"CONDITIONAL $250 Equipment Discount Included",
"meta_keyword":"Blackberry, 8100, pearl, cell, phone",
"short_description":"The BlackBerry 8100 Pearl is a departure from the form factor of previous BlackBerry devices",
"custom_layout_update":"",
"color":"23",
"status":"1",
"tax_class_id":"2",
"visibility":"4",
"weight":"15.2000",
"price":"349.9900",
"cost":"29.9900",
"name":"BlackBerry 8100 Pearl",
"manufacturer":"21",
"url_key":"blackberry-8100-pearl",
"meta_title":"BlackBerry 8100 Pearl",
"meta_description":"BlackBerry 8100 Pearl sports a large 240 x 260 screen",
"gift_message_available":"",
"options_container":"container2",
"custom_design":""}}
```

I need to extract some informations : name, price, description ... but I don't know how to do it.

I read some tutorials http://www.journaldev.com/2321/google-gson-api-for-json-processing-example-tutorial

The problem is that Magento Json files are very different and special comparing to this one for example:

```
{
  "empID": 100,
  "name": "David",
  "permanent": false,
  "address": {
    "street": "BTM 1st Stage",
    "city": "Bangalore",
    "zipcode": 560100
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    123456,
    987654
  ],
  "role": "Manager",
  "cities": [
    "Los Angeles",
    "New York"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "age": "28 years",
    "salary": "1000 Rs"
  }
}
```

Because we have "16"and "17"which are "dynamic".

Comment: Your first json is invalid.. missing comma after    "description":" Like the BlackBerry 7105t"

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: No it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first json is invalid..missing comma after `"description":"Like the BlackBerry 7105t"`

---

this type of json is a map,so 16 and 17 is the key in the map.

then here you can use the code to decode:

> BTW:*What I read from file is your json String*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = readFromFile(new File("json.txt"));
    HashMap<String, GObj> maps = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, GObj>>(){}.getType());
    System.out.println(maps.get("16").description);
}

static String readFromFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    scanner.close();
    return builder.toString();
}

static class GObj {
    public int    entity_id;
    public int    attribute_set_id;
    public int    status;
    public int    tax_class_id;
    public int    color;
    public int    visibility;
    public int    manufacturer;
    public double weight;
    public double price;
    public double cost;
    public String type_id;
    public String sku;
    public String model;
    public String dimension;
    public String description;
    public String in_depth;
    public String activation_information;
    public String meta_keyword;
    public String short_description;
    public String custom_layout_update;
    public String name;
    public String url_key;
    public String meta_title;
    public String meta_description;
    public String gift_message_available;
    public String options_container;
    public String custom_design;
}
```

Comment: I used this to access dynamically:  Iterator it = maps.keySet().iterator();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(maps.get(it.next()).price);

     }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike.
Finally, here's my java file:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
       String json = readFromFile(new File("test.txt"));


        HashMap<String, GObj> maps = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, GObj>>(){}.getType());
        System.out.println(maps.size());
        System.out.println(maps.keySet());
        Iterator it = maps.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(maps.get(it.next()).price);
        }




    }

    static String readFromFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
        return builder.toString();
    }


    static class GObj {
        public String    entity_id;
        public String    attribute_set_id;
        public String    status;
        public String    tax_class_id;
        public String    color;
        public String    visibility;
        public String    manufacturer;
        public String weight;
        public String price;
        public String cost;
        public String type_id;
        public String sku;
        public String model;
        public String dimension;
        public String description;
        public String in_depth;
        public String activation_information;
        public String meta_keyword;
        public String short_description;
        public String custom_layout_update;
        public String name;
        public String url_key;
        public String meta_title;
        public String meta_description;
        public String gift_message_available;
        public String options_container;
        public String custom_design;
    }
}
```

And the output is :

```
2
[17, 16]
349.9900
149.9900
```